# Why was this question bumped to the homepage?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm not sure why the system performed this action for this one:
[Why is the common emitter input insensitive to base width modulation?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/270599/why-is-the-common-emitter-input-insensitive-to-base-width-modulation)

What does "this question may have good or bad answers" mean?It looks like nobody interacted with the question in a while,so why did this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system periodically bumps questions with no accepted answer to the front page.  This will appear to have been done by the "community" user.

Comment: It's the first time I see a notification shown like that for a question(when you enter the question).I noticed only the "last action performed by Community" message when in the questions page.So it's the same thing.

Comment: Yup, SE changed the comment they label this with very recently